# Finding Max/Min values in user-defined integer array. Negative numbers included

Tags: java, arrays, max, min

### All of this works to some degree. Here's the issue:

1: User specifies array size. Let's assume size = 5.

2: User inputs *1 2 3 4 5*

3: MAX number and MIN number works. All good.

**ISSUE:**
2: User inputs *5 4 3 2 1*

3: MAX number fails. It's defaulted to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`

##### This is defined above:

```java
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE, max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

##### The Code is here:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) { //READ INPUT, find smallest / largest
            numbers[i] = myScanner.nextInt();
            sum += numbers[i]; //ADD Array element values to sum.
            if (numbers[i] < min) { //Loop through array to find smallest value
                min = numbers[i];
            } else if (numbers[i] > max) { //Loop through array to find largest value
                max = numbers[i];
            }
        }
```

Note: This is a code snippet. "sum" belongs to the rest of the code.

Comment: "MAX number fails. It's defaulted to Integer.MAX_VALUE" and `max = Integer.MIN_VALUE` don't fit. The loop looks fine ... except: don't use `else if` but just 2 separate if blocks (just delete the "else" keyword). Your code now reads as "if the number is not smaller than min check if its larger than max" whereas that should be independent, especially for the first value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the "else", the two conditions can be true.

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {largest
    numbers[i] = myScanner.nextInt();
    sum += numbers[i];
    if (numbers[i] < min) {
        min = numbers[i];
    }
    if (numbers[i] > max) {
        max = numbers[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you dry-run the code

User inputs 5 4 3 2 1

1. 5<min(Integer.MIN_VALUE) so min = 5
2. 4<min(5) so min = 4
3. 3<min(4) so min = 3
4. 2<min(3) so min = 2
5. 1<min(2) so min = 1

Since you are having an else-if condition.

It never goes to the else condition and max is always Integer.MIN_VALUE

So remove the else-if to if condition.

Answer (score 0):

just remove else in your code, because two condition can be true at the same time